# Ansible ping result into Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ping

I would like to make an Jinja2 template from the following Ansible script. Basically, the script checks if a host is reachable or not.

```
---
- name: check reachable hosts
  hosts: group1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
    ping_state: "failed"
  - debug: msg="play hosts {{ ansible_play_batch }}"
    run_once: true
  - ping:
    register: ping_result
    ignore_errors: yes
  - group_by: key=reachable
    when: ping_result|success
  - set_fact:
    ping_state: "OK"

- name: run command
  hosts: reachable
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="this is {{ ansible_hostname }}"

- name: print ping facts
  hosts: group1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - meta: clear_host_errors
  - debug:
    var: ping_state
```

In the Jinja2 template I would like to have all hostnames with their ping state. How I can achieve this?

Best regards,

Romain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a different approach, based on gathering facts on remote hosts and then processing the template on local host:

how to use:

add the [ping_test] group in your hosts with all the hosts you want to check connectivity against.

then the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: ping_test
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    newline_character: "\n"
  tasks:
  - name: print all
    debug:
      var: hostvars['{{item}}']['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses']
    with_items: "{{ groups['ping_test'] }}"

  - name: process template
    template:
      src: templates/ping_test.j2
      dest: /tmp/ping_test.txt
```

finally, the template `ping_test.j2` in `templates/` folder:

```
#################
REACHABLE units:
{% for host in groups['ping_test'] -%}
{% if hostvars[host]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] is defined -%}
{{newline_character}}- {{ host }} is pingable
{%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}

#################
UNREACHABLE units:
{% for host in groups['ping_test'] -%}
{% if hostvars[host]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] is not defined -%}
{{newline_character}}- {{ host }} is NOT pingable
{%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}

#################
```

run the playbook and you find a ping_test.txt file in your `/tmp`

example execution, last lines only:

```
PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
greenhat                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
rhel-green                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
rhel-red                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# cat /tmp/ping_test.txt 
#################
REACHABLE units:

- rhel-green is pingable
- greenhat is pingable
#################
UNREACHABLE units:

- rhel-red is NOT pingable
#################
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]#
```

i picked a random ansible fact out of the many available, the `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses`. You can check gathered facts and pick another one if it better suits your needs. the idea is that for a host that ansible cant connect to, this variable will not be defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does what I wanted.

Comment: glad to hear that it helped :)